# Regex: Validating US zip code

Tags: regex, validation

I'm looking for a regex that validates the US Zip Codes and cannot contain more then 2 0's at the start:

Eg: 00979 is a valid zip code (Puerto Rico)

But I want the user to refrain from entering something like 000979 or 00012

Valid Zipcodes are: 979, 0979, 00979, 970, 907, 0907, 00970 ...

Invalid Zipcodes are: 00000, 00012, 12, ...

I've come up with

```
/^\d[0-9][0-9]{1,3}[1-9]([\-]\d{4})?$/
```

but this does not validates 979. What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at other references regarding validation US Zip codes but none of them validates trailing 0's cases..

Comment: Is `01234` a valid entry?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? Normally zip codes are expressed as exactly 5 decimal digits (ignoring zip+4), so `979` would be invalid. Can you use a regexp to confirm that it's exactly 5 decimal digits *and then* convert to an integer and check that its value is at least 100? Or that it matches `^[0-9]{5}$` and *doesn't* match `^000`?

Comment: @anubhava: yes, it's a valid entry although I doubt if that zip code exists but I'm checking that on BE. I'm building this regex to do the FE validation before it comes to BE..

Comment: @KeithThompson: what you're saying is exactly what I had an argument with my PM. But since we were allowing users to enter 3 to 5 digits of zipcodes before, we don't want to change that but now we want to add this validation where trailing 0's are not allowed

Comment: That's odd. In my experience, `979` would be an invalid zip code, correctly written as `00979`. I'm not sure whether the Post Office would accept that form. But if you've decided to allow users to omit leading zeros (which applies only to the US east coast), then I guess that's what you need to do. My other question: do you actually **have** to do this with a single regular expression? It would be easier and clearer if you could use two separate tests.

Comment: One more question: can a user enter more than 5 digits? If the user's zip code is `00979`, can they enter `000979`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: when the user enters 979, in Backend code, we append 0's and hence the zip is 00979. There are lots of other valid 3 and 4 digit  zip codes as well :) And for the user, the user can enter: XXX, XXXX, XXXXX and XXXXX-XXXX. Anything other then this would be invalid.

Comment: Suppose the user enters `001`. That only has 2 leading zeros, but when you pad it to 5 digits it has 4 leading zeros.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, you're right. I probably would have to add another validation I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex that allows up to 2 zeroes at the start:

```
^(?!0{3})[0-9]{3,5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijrhvW/3)

Comment: after looking at your regex and playing with it, I figured a few more corner cases such as 970, 907, 9790, etc.. but for the most part, your regex is working :)

Comment: Yes, this is working for most of the cases.. Can't think of anymore edge cases. I'd also edit my question in order to list more edge cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

isn't that your \d is already filtering out 1 [0-9]?

/^\d      [0-9]       [0-9]{1,3}   1-9?$/

9       7                9                oops ...